# I feel like I have to find a way to cancel out the $n$'s but I'm not sure how to do so with the $\sin^2(11n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The limit is from $n$ to $\infty$, I tried dividing everything by $n^3$ but I don't know how to deal with that
$$ \frac{-4n^3+\sin^2(11n)}{n^3+17} $$

Comment: Hint: note that sin function is bounded by [-1,1] Do you know about l Hospitals rule?

Comment: Is the fraction in my suggested edit the correct one?

Comment: I'm familiar with it. Is that when you take the derivative of the numerator and denominator?

Comment: yes the [-4n^3+sin^2(11n)] is the numerator and the [n^3+17] is the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Using the squeeze theorem, for example:

$$-4\xleftarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{-4n^3}{n^3+17}\le\color{red}{\frac{-4n^2+\sin^211n}{n^3+17}}\le\frac{-4n^3+1}{n^3}=-4+\frac1{n^3}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}-4$$

Comment: What exactly is this squeeze theorem? This is probably the second time I've seen it.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is $-4$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-4n^3+\sin^2(11n)}{n^3+17}$$

If $n$ approaches infinity, the  $+\sin^2(11n)$ in the nominator (It is bounded by $[0,1]$) and $+17$ in the denominator do not matter anymore. Therefore the limit is the same as $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-4n^3}{n^3}$$ Which is $-4$.

Comment: Is this solution clear for you? Feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: So what does it mean exactly when something is bounded by [-1,1]? In this case would the +sin^2(11n) not matter just like the +17 and disappear?

Comment: Bounded by [-1,1] means:  The function will not exceed 1 or get below -1.

Comment: As for the limit: Just imagine n getting really really big. As for the ratio, it does make no diffecence now if we ad a finite number in the nominator or denominator.

Comment: Oh ok so that's why for the limit the +17 doesn't show. As for the other comment is it because the sin^2(11n) is bounded by [-1,1] why it doesn't show up in the limit either?

Comment: If you have $\frac{4*k}{k}$ where k is a very large number. What difference will it make to add something in the nominator/denominator? A very small one. While n approaches infinity it will do no difference at all for the limit.

Comment: Ah I see it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting up the fraction and then multiplying through one of the terms by $\frac{n^{-3}}{n^{-3}}$. $$\begin{align} \frac{-4n^3+\sin^2(11n)}{n^3+17} =\frac{\sin^2(11n)}{n^3+17} -\frac{4n^3}{n^3+17}\cdot\frac{n^{-3}}{n^{-3}}  \\ =\frac{\sin^2(11n)}{n^3+17} -\frac{4}{1+\frac{17}{n^3}} \end{align}$$ You should be able to see that $\frac{\sin^2(11n)}{n^3+17}$ converges to zero as $n \to \infty$ because the numerator $\sin^2(11n)$ is bounded between $0$ and $1$, hence the denominator will grow exponentially while the numerator is bounded. Then the term $-\frac{4}{1+\frac{17}{n^3}}$ is nice because  $\frac{17}{n^3}$ converges to zero as $n \to \infty$, so $-\frac{4}{1+\frac{17}{n^3}} \to -\frac{4}{1+0} = -4$. In conclusion, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-4n^3+\sin^2(11n)}{n^3+17}  = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin^2(11n)}{n^3+17} -\frac{4}{1+\frac{17}{n^3}}  = -4 $$

Comment: So 17/n^3 converges zero because the n is in the denominator and n is approaching infinity. Just to be clear if I'm getting this I'm going to use an example. Since n is approaching infinity that means n can be 454 and since n is in the denominator it would make the fraction 17/454^3 which of course would be an extremely small number that approaches zero? Is this correct?

Comment: @JMartinez You are absolutely correct! And the idea is that for all $n>454$, the fraction just keeps getting smaller and smaller.